# .htaccess redirect partial dynamic url

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect url as below example using .htaccess

From
app.domain1.com/g1/###/###
To
app.domain2.com/g1/###/###

From
app.domain1.com/g2/###/###
To
app.domain2.com/g2/###/###

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]  

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^app.domain1.com/g1/$
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://app.domain2.com/g2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I am using codeigniter so I will need first four line of .htaccess to remove index.php from url.
I used this code but it is not working.

Comment: You need to do these things in the correct order. Currently, every request that does not match an existing file or folder, gets rewritten to the index.php, and the `L` flag ends the current round of rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?app\.domain1\.com$
RewriteRule ^/g1/(.*)$ https://app.domain2.com/g1/$1 [R=301,END]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?app\.domain1\.com$
RewriteRule ^/g2/(.*)$ https://app.domain2.com/g2/$1 [R=301,END]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php?%{REQUEST_URI} [END]
```